# Tricky CSS layout of external (facebook like and google plusone) buttons

Tags: html, css, layout, facebook-like, google-plus-one

What is the best way to place/layout the google+1 and facebook Like buttons so they align neatly?

Currently, the first "thing" in my body is this heading, appearing on top of all pages (slightly modified after logging in): (linebreaks added for readability) :

```
<table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      &nbsp;
      <g:plusone size="small" href="https://www.apebroker.com/">
      </g:plusone>
      <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apebroker.com%2Findex.php&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="left"></td><td align="right">It's more fun after you
      <a href="https://www.apebroker.com/loginform.php">login</a>&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that this looks like crap. I know that pages don't need to look exactly the same in every browser, but acceptable ugliness has its limits.
The google button is nicely "vertically centered", while the facebook stuff kind of sticks to the top of the page, 0px down.
See this example: [image: no offset to facebook iframe]

I tried adding `padding:2px;` to the style in the facebook iframe, and sure, it came down a bit, but so did the google button too, and the entire heading grew, pushing down the `<hr>` below.

I obviously don't know much about iframes, but I've managed fine on my own until now.

In my global style sheet I have (amongst other things) this:

```
body {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px; 
 background-color:#e0e0b0; 
 color:#302010;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,Sans-serif; 
 font-size:100%;
}
```

And I don't want to change that, as it cascades to all sorts of things that I'm reluctant to break. If you want to check out the complete style sheet and HTML source, an example page can be found [here](https://www.apebroker.com/index.php?cmd=view&gameid=7).

Thank you in advance for any hints/suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is that the table cells are sizing themself based on the font size even though there isn't any text in the table.

The "correct" answer is not to use tables for layout.

However, if you explicitly set:

```
 <td align="left" style="font-size: 1px">
```

then your life will get slightly better as you'll be able to explicitly control the height of each of the cells and position things. At the moment despite you "asking" for a height of 21px, you're getting 26px.

After that the FB button will look nice and you'll need to move the +1 button around.

But, the real answer is not to use tables:

http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto

http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

and various others...

Comment: So, I take it you're saying that I should have one `<div>` for the googlebutton and another `<div>` for the FB button? That still doesn't tell me how to get them aligned height-wise. I now have removed the upper table, replaced it with three divs, one containing a `&nbsp;` (the middle one, to make the rest of the page appear in the correct place), one with the two buttons on the left, and one with the text to the right. Still looks bad, but the FB Like button height-centered now, Google+1 at the "bottom" instead now.

Answer (score 1):

How about plus one button, and it's width?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {lang: 'ru'}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix for this using  to encapsulate both fb:like and g:plus separately, and then setting the style of both  to style="vertical-align: top;". See example at http://www.clonearmycustoms.com/

Comment: Broken example. Can you elaborate?